# Удаление части строки после определённых символов

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Есть строка `str = "/abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop"`, как достать последнюю часть этой переменной – `mnop` или её середину `efgh`?

Comment: `items = "/abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop".split('/')` `print items[-1]` `print items[1]`

Comment: Можно еще попробовать [basename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename). Если конец строки будет без `/` в конце.

Answer (score 0):

Как мне кажется, самый простой вариант -- разбить строку по разделителю, используя метод split, и обращаться к полученному списку по индексам.

```
my_str = "/abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop"
items = my_str.split("/")
items[1] # abcd
items[-1] # mnop
```